# Boarding, NHL vs USA Hockey

Tags: rules, officiating, ice-hockey, nhl

in the USA Hockey casebook, I came across an interesting little nugget.

"Player A1 pushes teammate A2 into an opponent who is thrown against the boards violently enough to warrant a boarding penalty. Which Team A player is assessed the penalty?"

In this, a1 is called for boarding, instead of a2, unless a2 does something on his own that might deserve the call.

My question is, would the NHL use this approach too, for this kind of play? Ie, would it likely be penalized? The NHL rule is worded very specifically about a player who 'checks or pushes' an opponent who impacts the boards violently or dangerously; the USA hockey rule just says any 'action' that causes an opponent to go violently go into the boards.

They are just different enough to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess they are different because the rulebooks were written by different people.

At the end of the day I would expect both leagues to rule the same way.

The player that did the move gets the penality. In the example, A2 is basically just a tool for the check to go from A1 to the checked player. So it's him that gets the penality, not the player that was checked into another.